# Why does an error occur when trying to open a directory?

Tags: python, directory

so basically what I'm trying to do is get my files from my directory, following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-3vuBynnOE, and this kaggle dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/rishianand/devanagari-character-set

but it seems to error?

```py
#loading in data from kaggle 
#from :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-3vuBynnOE

#importing the libraries to see the actual images
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import os
import cv2

#the kaggle download had three folders(consonants, vowels and numbers), looking at the vowels number

DATADIR=  "C:/Users/binju/Downloads/archive.zip/Images/Images"
CAT= ['character_1_ka', 'character_2_kha',  'character_3_ga',  'character_4_gha',  'character_5_kna']
#paths directory


for category in CAT:
    path= os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
    print("this is the path:", path)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        print(img)
        #converting images into arrays
        img_array= cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap="gray")
        plt.show()
        break
    break
```

and the error:

```
  File "c:\Users\binju\csgr12project.py", line 29, in <module>Images\character_1_ka                                                              _ka
    for img in os.listdir(path):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:/Users/binju/Downloads/archive.zip/Images/Images/character_1_ka'
```

but when I go my actual file on my downloads, and press on it, this is what shows up:

```
C:\Users\binju\Downloads\archive.zip\Images\Images\character_01_ka
```

I changed the slashes because \ doesn't seem to work but / does... But I dont think the slashes are the problem

Comment: A zip file is not a directory?

Answer (score 0):

Your CAT contains

```
CAT= ['character_1_ka', 'character_2_kha',  'character_3_ga',  'character_4_gha',  'character_5_kna']
```

while the files are called

```
CAT= ['character_01_ka', 'character_02_kha',  'character_03_ga',  'character_04_gha',  'character_05_kna']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this one C:\\...\\...